# WebBrowser Control Loading Twice

Tags: c#

Alrighty, guys. If you'd like to pull your hair out, the I've got a great problem for you. This problem seems very rare, but it effects my program on a few different sites that have pages that load content twice.

For instance: http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=donuts&find_loc=78664&ns=1#start=20

If you visit this site, you'll notice that it loads, then reloads different data. That's because there is a parameter in the URL that says start=20, so the results should start at #20 instead of #10. No matter what that is set to, Yelp loads the first 10 results. Not sure why they do this, but this is a prime example of what absolutely breaks my program. :(

Basically, whenever my program has a page that loads, it copies the source code to a string so it can display it somewhere else. It's not really important- What is important is that the string needs to actually have the last thing that is loaded in the page. Whenever a page loads, then loads again, I am not sure how to catch it and it ruins the program by exiting the while loop, and copying the source code into the string called source.

Here is a snippit of some code that I reproduced the problem with. When I attempt to use this in a new program, it will copy the source code for the first pages' results instead of what it is changed to.

```
GetSite = "http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=donuts&find_loc=78664&ns=1#start=20";
webBrowser9.Navigate(GetSite);
while (webBrowser9.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    p++;
    if (p == 1000000)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Timeout error. Click OK to skip." + Environment.NewLine + "This could crash the program, but maybe not.");
        label15.Text = "Error Code: Timeout";
        break;
    }
    Application.DoEvents();
}
mshtml.HTMLDocument objHtmlDoc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser9.Document.DomDocument;
Source = objHtmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Comment: You must use webbrowser or you can use different object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/17034

Comment: @Tinwor : It is preferred. What else would you have? If I used something else, I don't think it would redirect me the way I need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you wait in `while` loop for the browser to finish loading data? 
Use [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and you can remember the document's URL from there.